# Roots of a polymomial of two variables in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to find out roots of a polynimaial
`f(x1,x2)` of degree 4. `Roots` command is showing error `"{l1,l2} is not a valid variable"`. I tried `FindRoot` command also. That is also showing some error. Please suggest how should I proceed.

Command given to mathematica is,
`FindRoot[f(x1,x2)==0, {x1,x2}]`

Comment: Just curious: a quadratic poly like x^2=4 has up to 2 roots only but in two variables x^2+y^2=4 the solution is a continuum of points of a circle. How is the program supposed to deliver such set of 'roots'?

Comment: Have you read the description of the tag you used for your question? It says: _'Mathematica has its own Stack Exchange site at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ and that site is the preferred place to ask questions about it.'_

Comment: Of you literally used `f(x1,x2)` then that is at least part of your problem. Mathematics uses square brackets [] around function arguments. Please try that change and report back what happens. If it doesn't work then show your complete exact input to Mathematics and we can try to track down the problem.